# How to tell clang to put debug symbol into executable binaries?

Tags: c++, c, macos, clang, llvm

My compile command  is in macOS Sierra is

```
clang -std=c11 -g -Wall -Werror -fsanitize=address -file.c -o file
```

after it compiles, it also generates an extra file.dSYM file which included all debug symbols. However, when I use WSL or other *nix system it will not generate such file, debug symbols were embedded into executable binaries.
So I just wondering is there a way to do the same in macOS with clang.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you compile a program in one pass, `clang` actually runs `dsymutil` for you, which is responsible for creating the `.dSYM` file. Thus, the solution to your problem is to compile and link separately, in which case `clang` won't automatically call `dsymutil`.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32297349/why-does-a-2-stage-command-line-build-with-clang-not-generate-a-dsym-directory) SO question for more details!