# different output for -fsanitize=address with clang++ vs g++

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, address-sanitizer

In the following code I have a problem. When I give it a vector that is still completely empty the code crashes, because vector.size() - 1 can't be negative, hence it wraps around. Because the vector is empty accessing container[0] is invalid.

```
using namespace std;

template<typename T, typename A>
std::string vec_to_python_list(
        const std::string& name,
        const vector<T, A>& container
        ) {
    std::stringstream stream(ios::out);
    stream << name << " = [" << '\n';
    for (typename vector<T, A>::size_type i = 0; i < container.size() - 1; i++)
        stream << "\t" << container[i] << ",\n";
    if (name.size() > 0)
        stream << "\t" << container[container.size() - 1] << "\n";
    stream << "]";
    return stream.str();
}
```

My question is about the output that it produces.

If I compile with g++ on Ubuntu-16.04

```
g++ -Wall -Wextra -std=c++14 -g -fsanitize=address -O0  -o test_kmeans test_kmeans.cpp
```

I obtain the next useful info:

```
#0 0x402a56 in std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > vec_to_python_list<double, std::allocator<double> >(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > const&) /home/hetepeperfan/programming/cpp/kmeans/test_kmeans.cpp:46
#1 0x401f07 in main /home/hetepeperfan/programming/cpp/kmeans/test_kmeans.cpp:66
#2 0x7f393881f82f in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x2082f)
#3 0x401ba8 in _start (/home/hetepeperfan/programming/cpp/kmeans/test_kmeans+0x401ba8)
```

However if i compile with clang++ (still on Ubuntu-16.04)

```
clang++ -Wall -Wextra -std=c++14 -g -fsanitize=address -O0  -o test_kmeans test_kmeans.cpp
```

I get less useful results:

```
#0 0x4eecae  (/home/hetepeperfan/programming/cpp/kmeans/test_kmeans+0x4eecae)
#1 0x4ee056  (/home/hetepeperfan/programming/cpp/kmeans/test_kmeans+0x4ee056)
#2 0x7f6ed883a82f  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x2082f)
#3 0x419838  (/home/hetepeperfan/programming/cpp/kmeans/test_kmeans+0x419838)
```

What am I do'ing wrong so that g++ with -fsanitize=address works and clang++ doesn't produce as useful results, It seems like the debugging symbols aren't added?

**EDIT**
The debug symbols seem to be present, because with gdb I can easily step through the code and with the --tui gdb option I can see my code, so that isn't the issue.

Comment: Related: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32297349/3871028)

Comment: @Ripi2 That's Apple stuff. OP is using Ubuntu.

Comment: @melpomene, Ripi2 didn't know at the time of writing, I added this information later to the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install the llvm-symbolizer. 
Also set the ASAN_SYMBOLIZER_PATH environment variable to something like

```
ASAN_SYMBOLIZER_PATH=/usr/lib/llvm-5.0/bin/llvm-symbolizer
```

llvm is looking for an executable named `llvm-symbolizer` not `llvm-symbolizer-3.8`, that's why the environment variable must point to `llvm-symbolizer` a filename that has no version number. If all your symbolizers have version numbers in their file name, make a symbolic link that has no version number in it.

Comment: Hi michael, thanks for your answer, however I think I've got the llvm-symbolizer on my path: `$which llvm-symbolizer-3.8 
/usr/bin/llvm-symbolizer-3.8` If I put that on the path I get: ==25910==ERROR: External symbolizer path is set to '/usr/bin/llvm-symbolizer-3.8' which isn't a known symbolizer. Please set the path to the llvm-symbolizer binary or other known tool.

Comment: Apparently, this is not enough since llvm looks for `llvm-symbolizer` not `llvm-symbolizer-3.8`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. It works now I've made a soft link in my working directory without the "-3.8" suffix to the one on in my /usr/bin directory and if I put that one on the the path `ASAN_SYMBOLIZER_PATH=./llvm-symbolizer` then it works. Seems a small packaging problem on Ubuntu-16.04

Comment: Glad to help. I have seen this tip in Jason Turner's "C++ weekly" on YouTube.