# Clang link debug_info in executable on OSX

Tags: macos, clang, dwarf

On OSX when you link a binary from multiple object files like this

```
clang++ -g myfile.cpp -o myfile.o
clang++ myfile.o -shared -o myfile.dylib
```

it will generate a `.debug_info` section (etc.) in `myfile.o` but in `myfile.dylib` it just stores a reference to `myfile.o` and you have to run `dsymutil myfile.dylib` manually. `dsymutil` links all the `.debug_info` sections from the object files together and stores them in a `myfile.dylib.dSYM` bundle.

My question is: is there a way to make Clang actually link the debug info during compilation and store it directly in `myfile.dylib`?

Or if that is not possible, is it possible to embed the `.dSYM` bundle inside the `.dylib` after it has been generated?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I want to know exactly this thing. 

Comment: I didn't, sorry!