# Debug information "DWARF" and crash logs

Tags: ios, xcode, dwarf, dsym

I am trying to map my understanding of "DWARF" vs "DWARF with dSYM file" debugging info formats to what I see in the crash information for different iOS build configurations.

I was trying to fix a problem, where crashes on the build with debug configuration were not symbolicated by default. These were my build settings before the problem was fixed -

Strip Linked Product - Debug - No, Release- Yes

Strip Debug Symbols during Copy - Debug - No, Release - Yes

Debug Information Format - Debug - DWARF, Release - DWARF with dSYM file

What got it to work was setting the Debug information format to "DWARF with dSYM File" for debug configuration as well.

My questions is - why do I need to to set the format to "DWARF with dSYM File" if I am specifying that the product should not be stripped of its symbols into a dSYM file (in the strip linked product setting)?

My (probably incorrect) understanding was that if I set it to DWARF, then all the debug information would be inside the app binary and I do not need a separate dSym file for symbolication? Please help me with a better understanding of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Apple's platforms, DWARF is never baked into the executable (except for unwind info). Enabling DWARF debug info just means that the .o files contain DWARF-formatted debugging info. The linker doesn't bring that into the executable, though.

If you request a dSYM file, a separate build step uses `dsymutil` to collect the debugging info from the .o files into a dSYM bundle or file.

Debuggers can use a map in the executable to look up the debug info in the .o files when needed, assuming you're debugging on the build machine. That's why you don't typically need a dSYM file for a Debug build. Symbolication doesn't have the executable, just a UUID for it. It could find the dSYM using the UUID, but it doesn't have the information to find the .o files.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12827463/1312143) by an Apple developer involved in implementing this stuff. Also, [this older wiki article](http://wiki.dwarfstd.org/index.php?title=Apple%27s_%22Lazy%22_DWARF_Scheme) he wrote.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and links. I think my source of confusion was that I thought "Strip linked product" both strips information from binary and transfers it to a dSym file. But I think I understand now that the dSym file can/is created in an earlier stage. The stripping phase just removes the information from the executable.