# What's the difference between DWARF and DWARF with dSYM file?

Tags: ios, xcode, crash-reports, dwarf, stripping

XCode supports those 2 values for this Build Setting:

Build Settings > Build Options > Debug Information Format.

Could anybody explain the differences?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The difference is that in the case of DWARF with dSYM file your Archive app.xcarchive (for adHoc distribution) contains also dSYM file needed for reverse symbolication of your code in crash reports. In general, .xcarchive contains

```
dSyms
Products
info.plist
```

So if you need it for external analysis of crash reports under archiving you app for distribution you should use DWARF with dSYM file.

Answer (score 26):

As always understanding the abbreviations help!

**[DWARF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DWARF) is a widely used, standardized debugging data format:**

> DWARF was originally designed along with [Executable and Linkable Format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) (ELF), although it is independent of object file formats. The name is a medieval fantasy complement to "ELF" **that has no official meaning**. Only that both (dwarf and elf) are mythological creatures

**[Debug Symbol](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2151/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008184-CH1-SYMBOLICATIONTROUBLESHOOTING) (dSYM):**

By default, debug builds of an application store the *debug symbols* inside the compiled binary while release builds of an application store the debug symbols in a companion dSYM file to reduce the binary size.

The Debug Symbol file and application binary are tied together on a per-build-basis by the build UUID. A new UUID is generated for each build of your application and uniquely identifies that build.

> For example, if you have a library libfoo.dylib, the debug symbol file
> would be libfoo.dylib.dSYM.
>
> <sub>From [here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/9293)</sub>

So long story short

- **DWARF** is just a debug file
- **DWARF with dSYM File** is a debug file along with symbolification file

> DWARF is embedded in the object files of the binary, but not in the binary itself (unlike stabs, which are linked into the binary proper). dsym extracts the DWARF info from the object files, puts it in a separate dSYM bundle and makes the binary refer to this bundle (instead of to the object files). [Docs](https://lists.apple.com/archives/xcode-users/2009/Apr/msg00034.html)

Also see [DWARF's official home page](http://wiki.dwarfstd.org/index.php/Main_Page)

---

**Pro tip:**

On our project's GitHub repo, on the releases section we have something like this:

[image]

We upload the `.ipa` and `dysm` file so then if 3 months from now a user has a weird crash for our 10.16 build then we'd go to this release branch and run it with this dsym and try to reproduce the issue.

More details under the hood from some Dwarf original authors/maintainers

- [where/how does Apples GCC store DWARF inside an executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10044697/where-how-does-apples-gcc-store-dwarf-inside-an-executable/12827463#12827463)
- [Difference between DWARF and DWARF with dSYM file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64469948/5175709)
- [DWARF Debugging Standard Wiki](https://wiki.dwarfstd.org/Apple%27s_%22Lazy%22_DWARF_Scheme.md)

Comment: Why might a developer prefer DWARF over DWARF w/ dsym? Are the perf implications for the build?

Comment: the dSYM is what allows you to attach the app process to Xcode and debug it. Imagine if you intended to make a secure banking app. You don't want to allow others to debug your code. Having dSYMS making it easier for others (hackers) to symbolicate your crash reports.

Comment: To answer "Why might a developer prefer DWARF over DWARF w/ dsym? Are the perf implications for the build?": DWARF w/ dsym takes significantly longer (i.e., the extra step of running the dsymutil). So often for local developer builds, `dwarf` is suitable. When building a release, `dwarf-with-dsym` is preferable, so you can store the dsym files as well for debugging crash reports from users.

Comment: Is there any difference if you choose the dwarf debug information, keep the unstripped executable in secret, then release with a stripped executable? I think it has the same effect with splitted dSYM file but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 20):

Both **DWARF** and **DWARF with dSYM** create DWARF debug information like on all other platforms, but they differ on where the debug information will be accessed when debugging or symbolicating:

**DWARF** means that the debug information is left in .o files and this debug information is not linked during the build process. Each .o file will contain unlinked DWARF and the debugger (LLDB, GDB) will link the debug information on the fly when debugging. The main executable contains a debug map contained in the symbol table which has everything that is needed to link the debug information. The maps contains STABS symbol entries that points to each .o file and tells the debugger or linker where everything needs to be linked (for functions, globals and static variables). The debug information will be less efficient since it is not linked, and each .o file can contain type definitions that are also found in other .o files, so the overall debug information size will be bigger. This is often most useful for the edit/compile/debug cycles for when you're implementing new features or trying to track down bugs. The benefit is you do not have to link the debug information during your build process. Not all tools that parse debug information support this mode of debug information, so you  might want create dSYM files if local crash reports on your system do not contain source file and line information in the backtraces. Tools like sample, ReportCrash, and Instruments that need to parse debug information might not support the **DWARF** setting.

**DWARF with dSYM** means that after you build your executable, a dSYM debug information file will be linked using a tool named `dsymutil`. `dsymutil` gets ran after your executable is linked to parse the debug map in the main executable and produce a dSYM file with all of the debug information. Linking the debug information can add to your build times if you have a lot of code in your project. The DWARF debug information in all of the .o files is intelligently linked into the dSYM file. Any code that was dead stripped will have its debug information removed, and the `dsymutil` will dedup types within the debug information, so the resulting DWARF is much smaller and more efficient. Use this setting when building your releases or if you have a build machine that is caching builds for others to download.

In order to find the dSYM file for an executable, the UUID from the main executable is copied into the dSYM file. A previous comment suggested that the UUID changes with each build even if the same source code and compiler was used, but this is not true. The UUID is a MD5 checksum of the parts of the binary that do not change due to debug information. Debug information can contain paths and other data that change depending on what directory the sources exist in. If the UUID was simply a MD5 checksum of the entire binary, then the UUID would be different for the same sources built with the same compiler if one was built in /tmp/myproj vs /users/data/myproj. So the UUID built into Darwin binaries will match if the important bits (__TEXT, __DATA, etc) are the same even if the project is built in different directories. This allows the UUID to be used to unique dSYM files across multiple builds that produce the same binary. If SDK header files or different compilers or linkers are used, the UUID can easily differ.

There is Spotlight importer for dSYM files knows how to extract the UUID from the dSYM file to make it possible for debuggers and other tools like sample, Instruments, ReportCrash and more to find the dSYM file for a binary even if the dSYM file is not right next to the binary. You can see the UUID of your binary by running `dwarfdump`:

```
$ dwarfdump --uuid ~/a.out
UUID: E76A2647-AFB4-3950-943A-CB1D701B7C07 (x86_64) ~/a.out
```

Then you can use the Spotlight window in your system to search for the dSYM file. There is also a command line tool for spotlight called "mdfind" that can be used:

```
$ mdfind E76A2647-AFB4-3950-943A-CB1D701B7C07
/Users/admin/a.out.dSYM
```

So to sum up: use **DWARF** for edit/compile/debug cycles if you have large projects and want to avoid the time it takes to link a dSYM file during your daily workflow. Use **DWARF with dSYM** all the time if you have smaller projects, doing release builds, or need other Apple tools that are not debuggers to be able to parse your debug information. Both formats contain the same kind of information and can be used for debugging, but not all tools can load the **DWARF** format where the DWARF is left in the .o files.

Comment: wow. Greg is actually one of the `lldb` authors!

Answer (score 4):

DWARF (debugging with attributed record formats) is a debugging file format used by many compilers and debuggers to support source-level debugging. It is the format of debugging information within an object file. The DWARF description of a program is a tree structure where each node can have children or siblings. The nodes might represent types, variables, or functions.

> source: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-dwarf-debug-format/index.html

---

DWARF with dSYM File stores the debug symbols for your app

Services like crashlytics use it to replace the symbols in the crash logs with the appropriate methods names so it will be readable and will make sense.

> source : [What's the dSYM and how to use it? (iOS SDK)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3656391/whats-the-dsym-and-how-to-use-it-ios-sdk)

Answer (score -1):

From "Project Editor Help":

Debug Information Format (DEBUG_INFORMATION_FORMAT)

The type of debug information to produce.

DWARF: Object files and linked products will use DWARF as the debug information format. dwarf

DWARF with dSYM File: Object files and linked products will use DWARF as the debug information format,and Xcode will also produce a dSYM file containing the debug information from the individual object files (except that a dSYM file is not needed and will not be created for static library or object file products). dwarf-with-dsym