# A bit confused in-regards to pitfalls that come along with defining functions in header files in C++

Tags: c++, header-files

I was told that the only event in which it's really a good idea to define functions in header files is if the function is marked inline or is a function template. Apparently,or so I was told, one of the key reasons for this is the one definition rule- a rule allowing only only one function definition per translation unit.I was told that you would get one definition of that function for every cpp file that includes that header. I am however having issues understanding how you would get one definition of that function for every cpp file in C++. I'm having a bit of trouble visualizing why that might be the case. So, would someone mind offering some insight into why that's the case? Cheers!

Comment: Related: [What exactly is One Definition Rule in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4192170/what-exactly-is-one-definition-rule-in-c)

Comment: Do you know how `#include` works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you `#include` a file, the compiler acts as if you'd just copy-pasted the file into the current file.

That is, if you have three files:

```
// header.h
void foo() {/* do stuff */}

// a.c
#include "header.h"
void a_func() {/* do stuff */}

// b.c
#include "header.h"
void b_func() {/* do stuff */}
```

then the compiler treats it as if you'd copied the contents of `header.h` into both `a.c` and `b.c` - that is, it behaves *exactly as if* you had:

```
// a.c
void foo() {/* do stuff */}
void a_func() {/* do stuff */}

// b.c
void foo() {/* do stuff */}
void b_func() {/* do stuff */}
```

Clearly, there are multiple definitions of `foo` here - as there's one in each file.

Comment: The ODR is definitely more advanced, but is outside the scope of the OP's question. It is closely related and is good information for suggesting further learning, but I think this answer is fine.

Comment: @immibis  Right, I am familiar with include guards. However, I'm still not really clear on how implementing functions in the header file will create a conflict with the one definition rule, but implementing them in a separate cpp file doesn't. What are the subtleties that make that the case? Thanks for taking the time to help me out!

Comment: @Mrcitrusboots There's another part of the one definition rule that says a non-inline function may only be defined once in the entire program. If you put the function implementation in a header file, and include that file in several translation units, then the function is defined in several translation units.

Comment: @immibis Thank you, that's exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

For simple function such as `sum`, *definition* would be:

```
double sum(double a, double b) { return a + b; }
```

and *declaration*:

```
double sum(double a, double b);
```

You place declaration in header, e.g. `sum.h`, so later you can use `sum`'s definition, e.g. placed in `sum.cpp`. Later, linker finds the definition of sum in `sum.o` [object file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3045652/657390).

Since `#include` pragma is replaced with headers' contents, if you place your function's definition in header, you'll have multiple identical functions and also linker error.